# Logging Soap Request and Response - Spring

Tags: spring-boot

I have in the code where we make external SOAP calls to a system.
I want to log the HTTP request and Response for these calls.
We have different implementation of calling SOAP like Spring WS, JAX RS.
So, basically I need to log all HTTP requests and responses we are making to this external system via SOAP.

Answer (score 1):

What I did is a configuration bean that you can enable or disable with an env var like this:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty("soap.debug")
public class DebugSOAPConfig {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DebugSOAPConfig.class);

@Value("${soap.environment}")
private String soapEnv;

@PostConstruct
public void dumpXML() {
    logger.debug(String.format("Debugging SOAP Env: %s", soapEnv));
    System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dumpTreshold", "10000");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I don't need them to print all the time, I need some way to handle it from the code as only based on some flagging I will have to print few request and responses. Any way to achieve this.